# Approximations of $L^p$ functions, convolutions, mollifiers, etc. (resource needed)

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lp-spaces, convolution

What is a good resource in which I can read about mollifiers, basic theorems regarding convolutions, smooth approximations of $L^p$ functions and the like? (the presence of exercises would be great, but not necessary)

The course I am taking is very random, there are no given references and the lecture notes are horrible. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Real Analysis" by Folland would be a possibility.

Also, many books on Fourier analysis/Harmonic Analysis treat this topic (possibly in greater generality than you need), e.g. Folland, "A course in harmonic analysis".

It would help if you added some more details: Are you only considering $\Bbb{R}^d$, or more general topological groups? Are you only interested in approximating in $L^p$, or more generally in the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}$?

Comment: I am only considering $\Bbb R^d$, and I am only interested in approximations in $L^p$. Thank you for the suggestion. I already looked at Folland's, but I was hoping to find some other resource (for many reasons, mainly because he doesn't elaborate much on these topics). Do you have something else in mind? (having now known these details)

Comment: @AhmedHussein: "Classical Fourier analysis" by Grafakos could be worth a shot. Are you interested in approximation in $L^p$, or also in pointwise convergence (a.e.)?

Comment: I am only interested in approximations in $L^p$. I just took a look at Grafakos', I found many things I was looking for and I'll probably stick with it for the next few days. Thanks!